# How to handle large documents?

Tags: json, azure-cosmosdb

I wrote an import program which reads XML files from disk, converts them to JSON and stores them into DocumentDB. There are index files which are stored using the Node.js SDK.

A second type of files contains chapters. These chapters are inserted into the index files using a stored procedure. The stored procedure gets the index document from the database, inserts the chapter document into the index document and writes the updated document back to the database.

After the third document I get an error back from the stored procedure saying that the execution of the stored procedure has been blocked, because it exceeded the resource limits several times. How can I handle this situation?

Comment: streaming ?? see streaming json e.g http://oboejs.com/

Comment: It sounds like you might want to use the attachment functionality of DocumentDB. I say this because it sounds like when you say, "index" you mean "table of contents" and when you say "chapter" you mean a lot of text. I'm imagining a situation where the entity that you call an "index file" is a document in DocumentDB and the rendered "book" (my word) with the chapters inserted is a big bunch of text that you could add as an attachment to the index file record ("document" in DocumentDB lingo). Would that work?

Comment: BTW, I created an npm package, [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils), that (among other things) will automatically delete and recreate your stored procedure once it hits that limit. There is currently a bug causing stored procedure blacklisting even when you terminate your stored procedure correctly. documentdb-utils also has guidance on how to structure your stored procedures so they pause and resume gracefully (See [Pattern for writing stored procedures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils#pattern-for-writing-stored-procedures)).

Comment: @Larry: That would not work, because the chapter files also conatin meta information which we need to filter the chapters by the consuming web application.

Comment: Now I changed the stored procedure. I followed an approach suggested by @Larry Maccherone.. When the call of the server sdk returns false, I set the response body accordingly and on the client side I delete and recreate the stored procedure.
Now the stored procedure does not get blocked anymore for execution, but I get a different error. The error is:
{"code":"429","message":"Message: {\\"Errors\\":[\\"Request rate is large\\"]}\\r\\nActivityId: 44bc0bcd-c94e-4175-a180-ccc1e69d3685, }

Comment: I added a real answer so you can accept it, since that worked for you. I also answered your question about how to deal with the 429 error code there.

Answer (score 0):

Providing an answer to the original question here instead of in comments and also addressing the second issue in the comments.

First the answer to the original question. Inside of a stored procedure, whenever you get a false in response to any database operation, you need to wrap up the store procedure immediately or risk that stored procedure being blacklisted. However, there is currently a bug causing stored procedure blacklisting even when you terminate your stored procedure correctly. To get around this, you can delete and then recreate the stored procedure. I have created an npm package, [documentdb-utils](https://www.npmjs.com/package/documentdb-utils), that automatically does this for you.

In the comments you indicated that once you got past that, you hit another limitation, "Request rate is large", code 429. That happens when you ignore the 'x-ms-retry-after-ms' header response. You are supposed to wait that many milliseconds before submitting your next request.

Here is the code in documentdb-utils that deals with this:

```
 delay = (ms, func) ->
   setTimeout(func, ms)

 processError = (err, header, toRetryIf429, nextIfNot429 = null) ->
   debug('processError()')
   if err.code is 429
     retryAfter = Number(header['x-ms-retry-after-ms'])
     timeLostToThrottling += retryAfter
     debug("Throttled. Retrying after delay of #{retryAfter}ms")
     delay(retryAfter, toRetryIf429)
   else if nextIfNot429?
     nextIfNot429()
   else
     callCallback(err)
```

Comment: I posted the same question on msdn. Last Friday Microsoft deployed a fix for the blacklist bug. It is not enough to handle only 429 for executing stored procedures. Meanwhile I handle 429 after each call to documentdb. That helped a little bit. But when chpaters into the index documents I still get a blcklist error although I'm cleaning up the stored procedure and I also handle 429s. I'm in contact with the Microsoft dev team. They are working on the problem.